# Requisição cross-origin bloqueada - PHP

Tags: php, javascript, cors

Olá!

Sei que há diversas perguntas sobre esse assunto, mas mesmo lendo as respostas eu ainda estou com problemas.
Já tentei colocar Access-Control-Allow-Origin no cabeçalho do arquivo .php, já tentei colocar também na configuração de virtualhost no Apache e nada parece dar certo.
Onde estou errando?

Já vi que se eu utilizar uma extensão ou desabilitar flags do navegador, funciona. Então possivelmente é algo que estou errando no lado do cliente? :/

> ```
>       Requisição cross-origin bloqueada: A política de mesma origem (Same Origin Policy) impede a leitura do recurso remoto em https://a.4cdn.org/wsg/1.json. (Motivo: o cabeçalho CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' não está presente).
> ```

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/trend.css">
        <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="trendings">
        <h3>Trending:</h3>

        <div>           
            <ol id="trending">              
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var node,textnode,a,btn;        
        $.getJSON("https://a.4cdn.org/wsg/1.json", function(json) {
            for(var i = 1; i < json.threads.length; i++){
                node = document.createElement("li");
                a = document.createElement('a');
                textnode = document.createTextNode(json.threads[i].posts[0].sub);
                a.appendChild(textnode);
                a.href="http://boards.4chan.org/wsg/thread/"+json.threads[i].posts[0].no;           
                document.getElementById("trending").appendChild(node).appendChild(a);
            }
        });     
    });

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Quem deve "colocar o header" é o site que você está se conectando, no caso o `https://a.4cdn.org/wsg/1.json` deve ter o `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

Comment: há algo que eu posso fazer para que essa requisição funcione?

Comment: O CORS foi feito para não funcionar. O que você pode fazer é um Proxying, o seu site pega o conteúdo e você pega este conteúdo o seu próprio website.

Comment: Um exemplo de "proxying" simples com curl: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/227766/3635