# Habilitar 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' no jQuery [xml]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-service, xml

Eu não tenho acesso ao **.htaccess** do servidor e preciso habilitar o cors no **jQuery**

O código para acessar o WebService é:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote',
        crossDomain:true,
        dataType: 'text/xml',
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

O request headers é:

```
Request Headers
:authority:finance.yahoo.com
:method:GET
:path:/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote
:scheme:https
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
origin:http://localhost
referer:http://localhost/biblioteca/cotacao/jQueryYahooFinance/
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/59.0.3071.109 Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36
```

No .htaccess eu ativaria usando:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

No php eu ativaria usando:

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` só pode ser ativado no servidor. O propósito dessa regra é o browser não poder aceder a conteúdo que o servidor não quer que seja acedido quando o dominio do pedido não fôr o mesmo que o do servidor.

Comment: Eu pensei que poderia, pois eu consigo pelo PHP.

Answer (score 1):

O deve ser adicionado no servidor do `.xml` (o que não é possivel pois é o servidor do Yahoo, só eles tem este controle) e **não** na sua página, se fosse possivel fazer diretamente isto pelo cliente seria uma falha de segurança e nem precisaria de controle de CORs.

No entanto é possivel criar um "web-proxy" com `curl` para contornar isto, um exemplo:

Crie um arquivo chamado `moedas.php` e adicione isto:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

//Define um User-agent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

//Retorna a resposta
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//Resposta
$data = curl_exec($ch);

if($data === false) {
    echo 'Erro ao executar o CURL: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ($httpcode !== 200) {
        header('X-PHP-Response-Code: ' . $httpcode, true, $httpcode);
        die('Erro ao requisitar o servidor');
    }
}

header('Content-Type: text/xml');

//Exibe dados
echo $data;
```

Então no Ajax chame:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'moedas.php',
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

> **Nota:** se estiver usando PHP 5.4+ pode trocar `header('X-PHP-Response-Code: ' . $httpcode, true, $httpcode);` por `http_response_code($httpcode);`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Está é uma maneira interessante.

Answer (score 0):

Se criar um arquivo php e fazer:

```
<?php
    call_user_func($_POST['funcao']);
    function cotacao(){
        /* Faço load do arquivo xml */
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('https://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote');
        /* Retono uma String xml bem formada */
    echo $xml->asXML();
    }
?>
```

E chamar este documento:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'documento.php',
        dataType: 'text/xml',
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Funciona que é uma maravilha, queria fazer esta chamada direta pelo jQuery, mas pelo o que entendi não tem como.

Comment: O problema desta solução é que tem servidores SHARED e VPS que bloqueiam no php.ini o `allow_url_fopen`, detalhes em: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/filesystem.configuration.php. Nesses servidores não é possivel habilitar, fora que usar assim em servidores com HTTPS pode não funcionar se não configurar os "certificados de segurança" no php.ini ou no `stream_context_create`, no curl é mais fácil configurar, ou até mesmo ignorar a segurança.

Comment: Obrigado pela informação.